# Single threaded workloads

Tags: algorithm, performance

There is some feeling about the CPUs manufactured today does not meet Moores Law anymore, at least for single threaded performance.

I wonder what kind of workloads we have to worry if single threaded performance does not scale.

Breaking a text to lines and pages is a quite serial work, but on the other hand any human readable books or pages are quite finite length and handled by current text processing algorithms.

"Bureaucracy code" (the code that makes new versions of Word feel sluggish over decades despite exponential CPU performance increase) do stagnate either in my opinion (the programmers can't handle abitrary complexity and the large software companies finally joined some battle for performance in mobile computing).

So what kind of algorithms at all would hurt us if single thread performance increase would come to an end?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. We don't "need" Moore's law, we exploit it. I mean we comsume the computing power that computers can provide us, not less, not more. Before the 50's, there was no computer power at all, and we did survive. In the current world, computers are busy waiting 99.99% of their time.

Comment: Smartphone may wait 99.99% of their time. Supercomputers or machines in Google's datacenter most likely not.
So my question can be also read as "Does the increase of useful computer use is slowing down by moores law slowing down?"

Comment: Your initial premise is faulty. Moore's Law (actually an observation by Gordon Moore in 1965) predicted that the number of transistors per square inch would double each year for the foreseeable future. Over time that worked out to every 18 months. "More transistors per square inch" does not necessarily mean that CPU speed will continue to increase. CPU speed is today limited more by heat dissipation and quantum effects than anything else. "Moore's Law" continues to hold.

Comment: Ok. So do we have any name for the law "the amount of bits effectively processed by a computer in some manner is increasing exponentially" ?

Comment: The vast majority of personal computers of all kinds is idle most of the time. Should Google need to double their horsepower requirements, they would just add a second floor. In HPC applications, researchers push the machines as far as they can so that they meet their paper's submission deadline. There is no real pressure for faster CPUs.

Comment: So you would say any "real" workload with some use for mankind is paralelizable, while single thread bounded applications are rare cases that always keep small and won't hurt that much?

Answer (score 0):

What you call "bureaucracy code" is not slow because the developers cannot handle the complexity anymore (todays WinWord isn't *that* more complex than a decade past). The cause for Word (used as an example here) feeling as stagnant as always is that developers do not develop in a vacuum, but there is money and time involved. I.e., real-world developers *always* take shortcuts wherever they can. Word will *always* be just as sluggy as before because it will always just skim the line between usability and annoyance, when running on an average consumer device. Using more CPU makes it more "sexy" (more sales). Making it faster will cost more while not really increasing sales. The project management has the top-level goal of making as much money as possible.

A contrary example would be NASA using stone-age CPUs for their spaceships - they don't bother about money, they have other goals (like stability/fault tolerance), and those goals are not helped by a huge overhead of CPU power.

"Worry" is never useful, in no aspect of life, so I would not worry. Can you rephrase what you actually mean? If you mean to ask if there will be some kind of global problem if/when Moore's Law comes to an end, then no, unless you happen to work in a part of industry that turns obsolete, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: I meant that bureucracy code won't get any slower today, as some level of bureaucracy is reached that harms developers and users likewise so we keep it somewhat limited today and I do not expect it to getting worse like it did for ages anymore.